# Can not get most accurate location in the first time in IOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-location

I'm developing an IOS application, that showing user's current location in Google Map when the application load. It's the first screen that I'm showing to users.

But for the first time, application shows incorrect location in the Google Map. Most cases it happens when we do a fresh install. From the second attempt application shows accurate location in the Map.

I'm using IOS default  to do this. Using horizontal accuracy & location age we are determining what we assume to be the most accurate current location of the user.

Is there any reason why this is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way iOS get you users location. Often the first location is the last known location, you can check the date on the location results to see how old it is.

The you get the location by triangulation of cellular and WiFi networks. After this location update the phone might have a good GPS signal and will give the most accurate location.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using GPS for get the location from the first time.